# Boost.Log: Configure flush frequency or buffer size?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I have been searching this site and the Boost.Log doc for a way to do this but have come up empty so far.

The doc (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html) mentions the ability to set a `text_stream_backend` to flush after each log record written by calling `auto_flush(true)`.

While this works well for debugging, I was wondering if it was possible to configure a custom number of log records received by the `core` (or `sink`?) before a `flush()` occurs.  My goal is to strike a balance between useful live logging (I can see the log records frequently enough with a `tail -f`) and performance.

Alternatively, would it be possible to configure the size of the buffer containing log records so that once it fills up, it gets flushed?

Comment: What you ask is not supported by Boost.Log.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I see.  Is the default behavior documented somewhere?  I'd like to know what determines when a flush occurs (with auto_flush off of course).

Comment: The default behavior is whatever the behavior of the underlying C/C++ runtime library. Boost.Log does not implement buffering of its own (apart from async sinks) and passes the formatted content to the file stream.

Comment: @AndreySemashev ah! So if I understand correctly, what I need to do is to create my own `ofstream`, configure its behavior and buffer size, and pass it to the backend with `add_stream()` ?

Comment: Hmmm, I realize now that if I use a `text_ostream_backend` instead of a `text_file_backend`, I lose `scan_for_files()` and `set_file_collector`.  Kind of a raw deal.  Oh well.

Comment: There is no portable API to configure internal buffering of file streams - neither in C++ nor in C (and C++ `ofstream` typically builds on top of C `FILE*`). This property is an implementation detail of the runtime library. If you really need to control buffering, you should implement a custom sink backend, which uses the core OS primitives internally, like file descriptors (POSIX) and file handles (Windows).

Comment: @AndreySemashev Ok thanks for the info